# Conditional aggregate calculations on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to make some calculations with the dataframe

| ID | Method | Country | Amount | Success |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 95 | Мир | Belarus | 6063 | 0 |
| 96 | Maestro | Japan | 4013 | 0 |
| 97 | American Express | Belarus | 1426 | 1 |
| 98 | Maestro | Belarus | 5692 | 1 |
| 99 | Mastercard | Russia | 6929 | 1 |

I would like to calculate average amount by Method and Country, number of payment, Success Rate and total amount of successful payments.

```
Success Rate = (Number of payments where Success = 1) / All payments
```

In SQL I would do this amazingly simple

```
    SELECT country,
           method,
           avg(amount),
           count(1),
           count(CASE WHEN success = 1 THEN id END) / count(1) AS conversion, 
sum(CASE WHEN success = 1 THEN amount END) sum_success, 
    FROM data
    GROUP BY country, method;
```

First two calculations are relatively simple in Python too.

```
df.groupby(['Country', 'Method']).agg({'Amount': ['mean', 'count']})
```

But the third, fourth calculations seems kinda impossible without a lot of effort.

Is there a way to do it quickly and elegant?

Please don't say that I could calculate Success Rate by taking mean() of Success column. I know that. I've simplified what I actually going to do and my real task couldn't be solved this way.

Comment: The built-in groupby aggregations are highly performant as they are implemented in cython. The trick with pandas is often simplifying a seemingly complex groupby aggregation into more fundamental building blocks that use stuff like `sum`, `mean`, `cummax`, etc. This often requires doing some vectorized calculation on the DataFrame followed by a built-in aggregation, which will be orders of magnitude more performant than any `.groupby().agg(my_custom_func)`. And many problems can be simplified in this manner. So really hard to say how to do your calculation without really knowing what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL can parse your statements before returning your results (it can even figure out the column names, even if they are upper or lower case)- SQL makes it easy this way, as long as you use the right keywords; in Pandas, more often than not, you have to be explicit; in this case, you have to create some of the columns before hand before aggregating - more often than not, it is faster to do it this way:

```
           # create the columns that will be needed    
(df.assign(sum_success = lambda df: df.Amount.where(df.Success==1), 
           conversion = lambda df:df.Success.eq(1))
   .groupby(['Country', 'Method'])
   .agg(Amount=('Amount', 'mean'), 
        count=('Amount', 'size'), 
        conversion=('conversion', 'sum'),
        sum_success = ('sum_success', 'sum'))
  .reset_index() # indexes are useful, so you may not reset ... it depends
   )
 
   Country            Method  Amount  count  conversion  sum_success
0  Belarus  American Express  1426.0      1           1       1426.0
1  Belarus           Maestro  5692.0      1           1       5692.0
2  Belarus               Мир  6063.0      1           0          0.0
3    Japan           Maestro  4013.0      1           0          0.0
4   Russia        Mastercard  6929.0      1           1       6929.0
```

Notice for the `conversion`, I did not have to create a conditional per se, I simply used the boolean result and summed it in the agg section. So, depending on the aggregation, you may have to adapt it to Pandas nuances.

As an aside, there is another data wrangling in Python - `datatable`, that allows for nesting calculations, similar to SQL. It is still growing, and not as feature rich as pandas.

Answer (score 1):

We can try taking the [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mean.html) where values [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) the case (1):

```
df.groupby(['Country', 'Method']).agg({'Amount': ['mean', 'count'],
                                       'Success': lambda s: s.eq(1).mean()})
```

```
                          Amount        Success
                            mean count <lambda>
Country Method                                 
Belarus American Express  1426.0     1      1.0
        Maestro           5692.0     1      1.0
        Мир               6063.0     1      0.0
Japan   Maestro           4013.0     1      0.0
Russia  Mastercard        6929.0     1      1.0
```

---

DataFrame Constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [95, 96, 97, 98, 99],
    'Method': ['Мир', 'Maestro', 'American Express', 'Maestro', 'Mastercard'],
    'Country': ['Belarus', 'Japan', 'Belarus', 'Belarus', 'Russia'],
    'Amount': [6063, 4013, 1426, 5692, 6929], 
    'Success': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
})
```

Comment: Your solution may work in case I need to calculate something using only one column. Thank you for that. Bu is there a way to do something similar, but with different columns in a condition. For example: calculate sum of amount, but only if success = 1.

Comment: You cannot perform aggregate operations are limited to a single column at a time. You'd have to use apply. This is a limitation of `pandas`.